# Python - get elapsed time using datetime

Tags: python, time

With the `datetime` module, I can get the current time, like so:

```
>>> datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2017-08-29 23:01:32'
```

I have access to the time at which a file was created, in the same format:

```
>>> data['created']
'2017-08-29 20:59:09'
```

Is there a way, using the `datetime` module, that I can calculate the time between the two, in hours?

Comment: You could calculate it pretty easily parsing it and using datetime.month/day/hour/etc properties, but it's not within datetime module. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing subtraction on two `datetime` objects will result in a `timedelta`. You can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to get that second `datetime` object, access the `seconds` attribute of that [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) and calculate the hours from there:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

file_created = datetime.strptime(data['created'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
difference = (datetime.now() - file_created).seconds

print("Hours since creation: " + str(difference // 3600)) # 3600 seconds in 1 hour
```