# discord.py How to calculate time from message since time to current time

Tags: python, discord.py

```
timestamp = message.created_at

print(timestamp)
```

This is the output when I run this code:

```
2022-07-22 06:02:12.934000
```

I want to calculate time from time since message was sent to this time

Comment: if it is string then you can convert it to `datetime.datetime` (using `strptime` for "string parse time") and substract from `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - get elapsed time using datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950850/python-get-elapsed-time-using-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is string then you can convert it to `datetime.datetime` using `strptime` ("string parse time") and substract from `datetime.datetime.now()`

If discord gives it directly as `datetime` then you don't even need use `strptime`.

```
import datetime

created_at = '2022-07-22 06:02:12.934000'

msg_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
now_time = datetime.datetime.now()

diff = now_time - msg_time

print('msg_time:', msg_time)
print('now_time:', now_time)
print('diff    :', diff)
```

Result:

```
msg_time: 2022-07-22 06:02:12.934000
now_time: 2022-07-22 13:09:53.106146
diff    : 7:07:40.172146
```

---

Read more in [datetime — Basic date and time types — Python 3.10.5 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)